# Displaying blog posts on HTML page

Tags: php, html, mysqli

```
include "connection file";
$query = "SELECT * FROM Blog";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
for($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++) {
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo "<div class="blogEntry"><h4>" . $row['title'] . "</h4><h5>" . $row['date'] . "</h5><p>"
    . $row['text'] . "</p></div>";
}
```

Hi, so, I'm trying to loop through all my blog posts and display them to the page in order so the newest entry is first but I can't seem to get it too work. tried a few different ways and always white screen! Any help would really be appreciated :). I'm also going to add a search function and filters, I don't need this now but any suggestions where to look to find info about implementing these would also be really helpful. Link to where I'm putting this code on my website: http://www.obeytoplay.com/. Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any error, if so could you post that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> tried a few different ways and always white screen!

That's because there's a syntax error in your code. Either escape the inner double quotes(`"`) using backslash(`\`) or use single quotes(`'`).

**Method(1):**

```
include "connection file";
$query = "SELECT * FROM Blog";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
for($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo "<div class=\"blogEntry\"><h4>" . $row['title'] . "</h4><h5>" . $row['date'] . "</h5><p>" . $row['text'] . "</p></div>";
}
```

**Method(2):**

```
include "connection file";
$query = "SELECT * FROM Blog";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
$num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
for($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo "<div class='blogEntry'><h4>" . $row['title'] . "</h4><h5>" . $row['date'] . "</h5><p>" . $row['text'] . "</p></div>";
}
```

> I'm trying to loop through all my blog posts and display them to the page in order so the newest entry is first

Use `ORDER BY` in conjunction with `SELECT` clause to reorder the result set, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Blog ORDER BY column_name DESC/ASC;
```

Here's the reference:

- [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help, completely forgot about escaping! Must have looked at it 100 times. So yeah there is no-longer a white screen but its not actually displaying any of the data, Ill have a look and get back if I work it out!

Comment: @JoshWindsor Error reporting should be turned on. Add these lines `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your PHP script and see if it yields any error or not.

Comment: Yeah drops the following
Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in "root"/blog.php on line 87

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in "root"/blog.php on line 88

Comment: @JoshWindsor Yes, `mysqli_query()` requires two parameters, first is your connection handler and second is your query. So your `mysqli_query()` statement should be like this, `mysqli_query($link, $query);`. Your `mysqli_num_rows($result);` is fine though. Please refer [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).